# what program should i use to code using the Python PyGame module

Tags: python, import, pygame

I've been looking on the internet for a program which can run pyjama, but i haven't found one... I've tried:

- Xcode
- IDLE
- The normal python launcher

I've checked and they're all Python 3, but I can't import the Pygame module.
I imagine that there is one somewhere, because, obviously, other people must have one.
I've tried this:

```
import pygame, sys
```

and:

```
import pygame
```

Comment: Did you install `pygame`?  It is a 3rd-party library, so it doesn't come with the standard implementation.

Comment: Are you looking for a software recommendation, or troubleshooting help?

Comment: I'm looking for software recommendation

Comment: and no, i didn't install it... i thought it came with it :P Ill try that... ty

Comment: how do i install it on a mac?

Comment: On OS X you use TextMate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install *pygame* with following this;

```
open cmd(console) and write this codes:
pip install pygame
```

Easiest way for this.

> For mac;

```
sudo pip install pygame
```

> And yes you have to write this in terminal
>
> Or download from here http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml manually.
>
> But my little advice is, pygame is not so simple, first improve yourself in Python more..
>
> Also check this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Cl4Crg7FE